# Asp.net MVC maxlength not working using data annotation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am using asp.net mvc 4 i am using [maxlength(2)] in my model but it is not working on client side validation i am new to asp.net mvc .here is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace RestrauntsMVC.Models
{
  public class Restraunts
  {

    public int id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(2),MinLength(1)]
    public int rating { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string location { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does other validations are working?

Comment: yes Required field is working fine..

Comment: Did you try `[Range(1, 2)]`. I think that MaxLength is for strings types..

Comment: yes the rage validator works but i am not sure why maxlength did not work..Thanks  Pabloker ..

Comment: Length: how many characters it could have. Range: Range of values it could have.

Comment: only two character minimum one..

Comment: I don't understand why an int field could have maxLength and minLength..i.e: minLength(1), maxLength(2) in your case is the same of range (0,99) isnt it?

Comment: yes in this case range can work but i only wanted if i can make it work using maxlength because integer could have min and max length

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answering myself to help future readers.I found out Maxlength and Minlength is for String not for integer.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.Linq;  
using System.Web;  
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;  
namespace RestrauntsMVC.Models
{
public class Restraunts
{
   
    public int id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Range(1,10,ErrorMessage="Rating must between 1 to 10")]        
    public int rating { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string location { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: MaxLength is used for specifying the maximum length of a property, not the maximum numeric value: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.maxlengthattribute%28v=vs.103%29.aspx

Comment: why did you answer your own answer ...?

Comment: @WiiMaxx because i found answer myself and i want to help other users also who will read in future.

Answer (score 3):

Like other mention is only for string so how about writing your own [ValidationAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ?

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

internal class MaxDigitsAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private int Max,
                Min;

    public MaxDigitsAttribute(int max, int min = 0)
    {
        Max = max;
        Min = min;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (!IsValid(value))
        {
            return new ValidationResult(this.FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
        }
        return null;
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        // you could do any custom validation you like
        if (value is int)
        {
            var stringValue = "" + (int)value;
            var length = stringValue.Length;
            if (length >= Min && length <= Max)
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```